# How do you omit file extensions when generating gulp-sitemap sitemaps?

Tags: javascript, nginx, gulp

I'm using `gulp-sitemap` to generate a sitemap. NGINX is configured to omit file types on the production site (eg. `/articles/account.html` becomes `/articles/account`) and `gulp-sitemap` includes file extensions (eg. `<url><loc>https://thewebsite.com/articles/account.html</loc></url>`. How would you go about omitting (or removing, I suppose) the file extensions from the sitemap? Preference is given to omitting over removing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking closer at the documentation, you can alter the contents of the `<loc>` element by including `getLoc` in the root of your `gulp-sitemap` configs, like so:

```
getLoc: (siteUrl, loc, entry) => {
    let fileExtensions = /\.[^/.]+$/;
    return loc.replace(fileExtensions, "");
}
```